# Can we define the zero potential at an imaginary point?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, potential-energy, complex-numbers

Consider a force field defined as

$$\vec{F}(x) = \left(\frac{A}{x^2}-B\right)\hat{i}\space$$

where $A, B$ are positive constants. We want to get the potential energy function for this field. We can integrate this,

$$U(x_f)-U(x_i) = -\int_{x_i}^{x_f} Fdx= \left(\frac{A}{x_f}+Bx_f\right)-\left(\frac{A}{x_i}+Bx_i\right)$$

Now, we want to define a zero potential. Can we do so at $x=\sqrt{-\frac{A}{B}}$? (which is an imaginary point) Because putting this into the equation makes the last term on the RHS zero giving a simpler expression.

Specifically, is it valid for us to define the zero of potential energy function at an imaginary point? Does talking about imaginary numbers even make sense when talking about the potential of a force field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no such thing as an imaginary *point*. In other words, you can certainly plug imaginary numbers into a formula, but those imaginary numbers don't represent points in space, and thus the results you get will not represent the conditions at any actual point.

However, you don't need an actual point in space for this purpose. The potential energy field only needs to satisfy $\vec{F}(\vec{x}) = -\vec{\nabla}U(\vec{x})$, and that definition allows you to include an arbitrary constant in the potential. The constant doesn't actually need to be the value of the potential at a physical point. (As a corollary, there is no need to have $U=0$ anywhere.) So you can write

$$U(x) = \frac{A}{x} + Bx + C$$

and then arbitrarily choose the value of $C$, for example $C = 0$; you don't need to set $C$ to the value of $U$ at some point, as you did in your question.

Answer (score 2):

It is up to you where to define the zero potential (potential energy undefined up to a constant, so by adding any constant, the zero becomes anywhere you want it), but let's consider the point where the potential itself is minimum and subtract this value so that the potential is everywhere positive except at it's minimum (just a convention)
$$\vec{F} = \left(\frac{A}{x^2} - B\right)\hat{x}$$
$$U(x) - U(x_0) = \left( \frac{A}{x} + Bx\right) - \left( \frac{A}{x0} + Bx_0\right)$$
This potential is positive everywhere for $x>0$. The minimum of this potential happens at 
$$\frac{dU(x)}{dx} = B - \frac{A}{x^2}\implies x_\text{min} = \sqrt{\frac{B}{A}}$$
Assuming you're only interested in the region $x>0$

Now $U(x_\text{min}) = \sqrt{\frac{B}{A}}B\left(1+\frac{A^2}{B^2} \right)$, and you can redefine your potential to be $U(x)\rightarrow U(x) - U(x_\text{min})$, in which case your potential is indeed zero now at $x_\text{min}$

[image: graph of original potential]

[image: graph of potential with minimum at zero]

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm unable to see how that answers my question.

Comment: @Gerard You can add any constant you want to a potential without changing the force.  In this case your potential was never zero (that's what an imaginary zero tells you), but by shifting it down enough you can make the zero of the potential be at the minimum.  If you lower it less (or raise it) then you don't get a zero, if you lower it more then you get two zeros.

Comment: @Timaeus: I know that. My question is if it is valid for me to *define* a zero at an imaginary $x$?

Comment: @Gerard Don't do it. Maybe if you first make a full course of study on complex analysis then it can motivate you about how to shift your potential. But defining the square root function in complex variables is hard, there are two square roots, and with reals we can pick the positive one, for complex numbers there is no natural universal square root.  That means, among other things, that the "rule" $\sqrt{ab}=\sqrt{a}\sqrt{b}$ no longer holds when you consider complex numbers. So do not use complex numbers if you don't know how they work, it could come and bite you without you realizing it.

Comment: It seems that you meant to write $x_\text{min}$ instead of $x_0$, so I edited that, but I'm not sure; if that's not what you meant, please change it back.

Comment: I indeed wanted $x_0$ since at that time im only defining thr difference potentain between any two points

Comment: Hm, okay, though it's not really clear to me why you say that potential $U(x) - U(x_0)$ is positive everywhere, or why you say it is the potential with the minimum value subtracted.

Comment: It is positive only for x>0. If it was not always positive there, then it must be zero somewhere in x>0, then i chose that as my zero potential point without having to subtract anything... But if it is zero everywhere AND you require to define a unique zero potentian point, then you must subtract the value at minimum so you can get a unique zero potential point

Answer (score 0):

There was a mistake in the Integration: $- \int_{x_i}^{x_f} F dx = [\frac{A}{x}+\frac{1}{2}Bx^2]_{x_i}^{x_f}$.

When you set the potential difference $U(x_f)-U(x_i)$ to Zero, you will get an $x$ that is always a real number; you will have $x = (\frac{-2A}{B})^{\frac{1}{3}}$.

Usually, imaginary potentials are unphysical; every measurement of physical quantities must be represented in form of real numbers.

Comment: The question has been edited so that at least your first sentence no longer applies.